# just installed dotnet, dot new console and dotnet --version are working but dotnet run gives error. I'm trying to edit unity scripts from vscode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, intellisense, dotnetnuke

I'm following [this guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity) to connect unity with VScode.
This guide led me to [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/dotnet)

After installing dotnet i run the following commands according to guide and got a long list of errors.

```
PS C:\Users\SMME>   dotnet new console --force

Processing post-creation actions...
Running 'dotnet restore' on C:\Users\SMME\SMME.csproj...
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored C:\Users\SMME\SMME.csproj (in 92 ms).
Restore succeeded.


PS C:\Users\SMME> dotnet --version
6.0.404
PS C:\Users\SMME> dotnet run
C:\Users\SMME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\tcl\tix8.4.3\pref\Blue.cs(1,1): error CS1024: Preprocessor directive expected [C:\Users\SMM
E\SMME.csproj]
C:\Users\SMME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\tcl\tix8.4.3\pref\Bisque.cs(1,1): error CS1024: Preprocessor directive expected [C:\Users\S
MME\SMME.csproj]
C:\Users\SMME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\tcl\tix8.4.3\pref\Blue.cs(2,1): error CS1024: Preprocessor directive expected [C:\Users\SMM 
E\SMME.csproj]
C:\Users\SMME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\tcl\tix8.4.3\pref\Bisque.cs(2,1): error CS1024: Preprocessor directive expected [C:\Users\S 
MME\SMME.csproj]
C:\Users\SMME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\tcl\tix8.4.3\pref\Bisque.cs(3,1): error CS1024: Preprocessor directive expected [C:\Users\S 
MME\SMME.csproj]
C:\Users\SMME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\tcl\tix8.4.3\pref\Blue.cs(3,1): error CS1024: Preprocessor directive expected [C:\Users\SMM 
E\SMME.csproj]

Many line of similar errors

C:\Users\SMME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\tcl\tix8.4.3\pref\WmDefault.cs(43,42): error CS7000: Unexpected use of an aliased name [C:\ 
Users\SMME\SMME.csproj]
C:\Users\SMME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\tcl\tix8.4.3\pref\WmDefault.cs(43,55): error CS1002: ; expected [C:\Users\SMME\SMME.csproj] 

The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.
```

Contents of SMME.csproj are

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Please help if you have any idea why my original code was not working or this new dotnet installation is not working.

Actually I was using unity and scripting with vscode.
I got stuck here following the pathway from unity learn.

Create a new DetectCollisions.cs script, add it to each animal prefab, then open it
Before the final } add OnTriggerEnter function using autocomplete
In OnTriggerEnter, put Destroy(gameObject);, then test
In OnTriggerEnter, put Destroy(other.gameObject);

My vscode was not autocompleting `OnTriggerEnter` function, so i manually typed it but didn't work too. I searched for a solution in unity forums, reddit and stack exchange, some suggested to change unity editor settings while other VScode settings but nothing worked.

After trying everyth i deleted VScode completely with extensions and all .NET sdk's that i had installed.

Now i'm trying to install everyth from scratch but I got stuck at very first step.

Comment: Was probably not a good idea to create your project directly in your home directory. Better create and enter a new directory before `dotnet new`.

Comment: If this has anything to do with DNN (DotNetNuke) as it is labeled - DNN runs on Web Forms, so it needs .Net Framework 4.8, not DotNet Core. But maybe this label was added by mistake...